# can any one give me more details about journald and syslog

Tags: linux, boot, rsyslog, systemd-journald

Can any one help me in understanding the difference between journald and rsyslog and advantages, disadvantages for each one, which one I should use?

Comment: On modern systems syslogs are redirected into systemd-journald. The latter can forward them to daemons like rsyslogd if configured to do so. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73714497/14393739

Comment: this should be on [unix.se]

Answer (score 3):

**Journald** is the part of systemd that deals with logging - systemd, at its core, is in charge of managing services: it starts them up and keeps them alive.

It was originally designed for local logs on desktops – where there are not that many logs. On the other hand, **rsyslog** was designed for high-performance central log collections from the ground up.

**Rsyslog** can collect logs from many more sources, including pipes, sockets, and files. File sources are especially important, as many applications – like web servers – log to files and do that at a rate that **journald** cannot handle.

---

Both use **syslog** protocol. So you *could* use **rsyslog** and **journald** on the same machine without any problems.

The **rsyslog** modules `imjournal` (input) and `omjournal` output make it possible for rsyslog to read and write to the journal.

So if you write something to **rsyslog**, it will only appear in journald if you've configured the `omjournal` module.