# Why Syslogs from a program is watched from the journal command?

Tags: linux, systemd, syslog, systemd-journald

I am working on a program that sends logs with `syslog()`. Then I configured `rsyslog` service to save logs in a file under `Linux`. Most of the time this process works normally. But sometimes, some of the logs are not sent to `rsyslog`. Instead, I can watch them when I use the `journalctl -f -u Myservice` command. I am using the `Debian Jessie` version of `Linux`. Do you have any idea what is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: `I use the journal -f` Don't you use `journalctl`?

Comment: You should share the content of the systemd service which launches your application. By default stderr and stdout of the programs launched through systemd go into the journal.

Comment: You can also share the result of "systemctl status your_service | cat"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a good answer. In the `rsyslog` config file in we can add different methods to get the messages. I had many filters with the `contains` filter. this significantly reduced the performance since it needs to completely search the string for the filter value. Then I found that the `startswith` filter is far better in searching for a value in a string. I changed the message structure so that I can use the `startswith` filter. then I changed the `rsyslog` filter to `startswith`. now the performance is much better and no message sent to the journal.
the syntax is like this:

`:msg, startswith, "val"  # instead of (:msg, contains, "val")`

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer your question.

Answer (score 6):

#### Loosely speaking, with systemd, the logs are managed as follow:

`Process calls syslog()` **--writes in-->** `/dev/log = /run/systemd/journal/dev-log` **--read by-->** `systemd-journald` **--forwards to-->** `/run/systemd/journal/syslog` **--read by-->** `rsyslogd`

#### Let's look at it in more details...

*/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald-dev-log.socket* is the systemd socket unit to capture the messages from */dev/log*:

```
[...]
[Socket]
Service=systemd-journald.service
ListenDatagram=/run/systemd/journal/dev-log
Symlinks=/dev/log
SocketMode=0666
[...]
```

In the above socket unit, there are two important things:

- The service which is triggered for this socket is [systemd-journald](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-journald.service.8.html);
- */dev/log* is a symbolic link onto */run/systemd/journal/dev-log*:

```bash
$ ls -l /dev/log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 sept.  14 09:47 /dev/log -> /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
$ ls -l /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 sept.  14 09:47 /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
```

Hence **any process calling `syslog()` actually writes into */dev/log* synonymous of */run/systemd/journal/dev-log*. As systemd-journald reads from this socket, this makes it capture the logs of all the processes writing into */dev/log***. But systemd implements a mechanism to forward those logs to any "registered" service.

There is a *syslog.socket* unit which sets up the */run/systemd/journal/syslog* socket:

```
[...]
[Socket]
ListenDatagram=/run/systemd/journal/syslog
[...]
```

The corresponding *syslog.service* is triggered afterwards. The latter is actually a symbolic link onto the actual syslog service (e.g. [rsyslogd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rsyslogd.8.html) or [syslog-ng](https://linux.die.net/man/8/syslog-ng)). Here is an example, where it is a symbolic link onto *rsyslog.service*:

```bash
$ ls -l /etc/systemd/system/syslog.service 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 juin    5  2021 /etc/systemd/system/syslog.service -> /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service
```

The content of the latter service, executes `rsyslogd` daemon:

```
[...]
[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
[...]
```

We can verify its activation looking at the status of the *syslog* service (field "TriggeredBy"):

```
$ systemctl status syslog | cat
* rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-09-14 09:47:22 CEST; 32min ago
TriggeredBy: * syslog.socket
       Docs: man:rsyslogd(8)
             https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/
   Main PID: 728 (rsyslogd)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 18404)
     Memory: 3.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/rsyslog.service
             `-728 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
sept. 14 09:47:22 xxx systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
sept. 14 09:47:22 xxx rsyslogd[728]: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.2001.0]
```

The startup messages above shows that `rsyslogd` is passed the unix socket */run/systemd/journal/syslog* (file descriptor id 3). This is managed by the [imuxsock](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.html) module of `rsyslogd`. This is indeed part of the file descriptors opened by `rsyslogd` process:

```
$ sudo ls -l /proc/`pidof rsyslogd`/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 1 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 10 -> /var/log/kern.log
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 11 -> /var/log/mail.log
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 2 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 3 -> 'socket:[1339]'
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 4 -> /dev/urandom
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 5 -> 'socket:[36221]'
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 6 -> /proc/kmsg
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 7 -> 'socket:[36999]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 8 -> /var/log/syslog
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 sept.  14 09:47 9 -> /var/log/auth.log
```

The [configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) of `systemd-journald` decides if what is read from */run/systemd/journal/dev-log* is forwarded or not to */run/systemd/journal/syslog*:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/journald.conf | grep ForwardToSyslog
#ForwardToSyslog=yes
```

The above commented line means that the default is **"yes"**.

#### To answer the OP's question

If some of the logs sent by the processes are not seen in `rsyslogd`'s output but seen in the `systemd-journald`'s output, this may mean that `rsyslogd` is not started early enough compared to the application. So, the latter's logging are read by `systemd-journald` but are not forwarded to `rsyslogd`. The latter starts in the `systemd`'s *multi-user.target* whereas systemd-journald is launched at the very beginning of the system startup.
To verify that, the result of `systemctl status syslog.service` displays the activation date. Compare it to the activation date of *systemd-journald.service* and the one of the application.
A synchronization key like "After=syslog.service" may be missing in the service file of the application.

#### Further references

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/syslog/

Comment: incredibly detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on whether or not the `rsyslog` service is running. Please check if `rsyslog` is running when you face the issue.